# How to scroll jQuery ui tabs?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a div with 600px X 150px and i need to paste there a jQuery ui tabs. There will be only 2 tabs, but each tab will contain a lot of text and images, but i don't want to resize div. If i insert overflow option in css to div or .ui-tabs there appear 2 scrolls - 1 from div and another in tab and it scrolls all tab panel.
Question: how to insert vertical scroll into tab content?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think I have a solution for you, if i understand your question correctly.  Here's the [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/bSdbG/3/) on jsFiddle.

I added two classes, one that's applied to the overall tab element and one that's applied to each tab panel.

```
.container{
    width: 600px;
}
.panel{
    height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

(The `container` class could also be renamed to `ui-tabs` so that you add to the jQuery UI `ui-tabs` class, and the `panel` class could be renamed to `ui-tabs-panel` so that you add to the jQuery UI `ui-tabs-panel` class.)

Here's the mark-up that I used...

```
<div class='main'>
    <div id="tabs" class='container'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1" class='panel'>
            <p>tab1 text...</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2" class='panel'>
            <p>tab2 text...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I hook this up with some jQuery UI tab magic:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

I end up with a single scroll bar inside the tab.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

just use css for ui-tab-content class its like add the css code to any where in your style sheets hope you will be done.

```
.ui-tab-content, .ui-tabs-panel{overflow: auto;}
```

Thanks